# How can I make my server continue working without maintaining ssh connection?

Tags: server, ssh, webserver, erlang

I connect to my server via ssh that has erlang and cowboy installed on it for running my webpage.

```
ssh root@my.ip.adress
```

I then start up my webapp by doing;

```
./_rel/web_server_example/bin/web_server_example console
```

Which leaves me at a final line containing;

```
(web_server_example@127.0.0.1)1>
```

the erlang prompt.
Now I need both the server and my home computer that is connected to it, because if I close the terminal it stops the erlang program on the server. How can I keep the program running and have my home computer off?

Comment: // , If you have time, and you're going to use this server for a long time, I recommend that you find out the "prototypical" way to do things for your server family or corporation. This will save a lot of time in the long run, if you come across a head-scratcher of a problem on this server in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have (at least) 2 options:

1) Use `nohup`. Command:

```
nohup ./_rel/web_server_example/bin/web_server_example console &
```

then you can exit your ssh session. The output of your process will be redirected to file nohup.out

2) Use GNU screen. You will likely need to install it first: `apt-get install screen`. Then:

```
screen bash
./_rel/web_server_example/bin/web_server_example console
<Ctrl-A> D
```

At this stage you will have a screen session running in the background. You can exit your ssh session.
The beauty of the screen way of doing things is that you can re-attach later. Log on to that server and type in command `screen -r`. You will back to your `web_server_example` command and you can do things like pressing  to interrupt it or interract with it in some other way.